# Keras - Neural Network learns correctly trend of the data, but not amplitude

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I built a Neural Network in Keras to learn a mapping between 4 coordinates `x,y,z,d` (with `d=sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)`) and a scalar value. My training set is made of 1500 values of `x,y,z,d`, associated to 1500 values of the scalar function. My testing set has 500 samples.

My neural network produces correct "trend" of the data, but not the correct amplitude. The plots below should make it clear in what sense. They show the value of the scalar function for the training and testing set; in each plot, the original sample and the NN prediction are shown. I would like to ask for indications on how to have the NN correctly learn the amplitude as well, avoiding the 'interpolation' effect clearly visible in the plots.

```
from __future__ import division
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers


input_sig = Input(batch_shape=(None,4))
output = Dense(1)(input_sig)

NN = Model(input_sig, output)
nadam = optimizers.Nadam()
NN.compile(optimizer=nadam, loss='logcosh', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = NN.fit(x = x_train, y = y_train,
                    epochs=1000,
                    batch_size=100,
                    validation_split=0.2)

prediction_training = np.squeeze(NN.predict(x_train))
prediction_testing = np.squeeze(NN.predict(x_test))
plt.plot(y_train, color='blue', label='Original training')
plt.plot(prediction_training, color='red', label='Prediction training')
plt.legend(fontsize='x-large')
plt.show()
plt.close()

plt.plot(y_test, color='blue', label='Original testing')
plt.plot(prediction_testing, color='red', label='Prediction testing')
plt.legend(fontsize='x-large')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

## TRAINING SET PLOT

[image]

## TESTING SET PLOT

[image]

Comment: It's unclear to me how you generated `x_train` and `y_train`. And if there is no dependency among the samples, I don't think there is a "trend" in your data.

Comment: On what basis are you saying that it has learned the "trend"? It's not that clear to me if it actually has from the images at least. For example, how do you know if the model is not fluctuating between the range randomly?

Comment: @thushv89 I said it has correctly learnt the trend because, if you zoom in the plot, you can see that the red line "follows" the movements of the blue line. However, the NN fails to produce the spikes in the signal, as well as more generally to produce a signal that is as high as the original one

Comment: @HanWang I see your point. But, I don't feel like it has learned (this is my opinion). I feel the data is too volatile to learn from. Can you use some data normalization to make the lines smoother? Then you might have a better chance of learning something.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to build a feedforward neural network to learn the function

`d=sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)`

So as the function states, the input should be a 3D vector `[x, y, z]`, and the output should be a scalar value `d`. These are your `x_train` and `y_train`.

A non-linear `Dense` layer in Keras should be able to learn it (Note: you need to specify the non-linear activation function like `Dense(..., activation='sigmoid')`). Otherwise the `Dense` layer will be linear and only performs linear transformation, which may not be capable to learn the non-linear function very well.

Another thing that needs to pay attention is most activation functions have limited range of values. e.g. `sigmoid` ranges in `(0,1)`, which means even multiplied with a weight `w`, it still cannot fit `d` with arbitrary `[x, y, z]`. Alternatively, it's a good idea to learn `[x, y, z]` with certain range of values.

Comment: I don't have to learn the function `d=sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)`. My `x_train` is made of a set of coordinates `x,y,z`, to which I can add `d=sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)`, so that I have four coordinates. My `y_train` is a scalar value (NOT `d`) which represents some physical quantity associated to the coordinates

Comment: @johnhenry Then `d` seems to be a redundant input since it is clearly dependent on `x,y,z`. So basically your task is to generate some physical quantity with neural network given `x,y,z`?

Comment: yes that is correct. `d` seems to be redundant, I agree, but since there is some dependence of the physical quantity to be learnt from the distance `d`, I thought it may help to explicitly feed it into the network